# How do I run a container from the command line in Kubernetes (like docker run)?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to run a one-off container from the command line in my Kubernetes cluster. The equivalent of:

```
docker run --rm -it centos /bin/bash
```

Is there a `kubectl` equivalent?

Answer (score 75):

The `kubectl` equivalent of

```
docker run --rm -it centos /bin/bash
```

is

```
kubectl run tmp-shell --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image centos -- /bin/bash
```

Notes:

- This will create a Pod named `tmp-shell`. If you don't specify `--restart=Never`, a Deploment will be created instead (credit: Urosh T's answer).
- `--rm` ensures the Pod is deleted when the shell exits.
- If you want to detach from the shell and leave it running with the ability to re-attach, omit the `--rm`. You will then be able to reattach with: `kubectl attach $pod-name -c $pod-container -i -t` after you exit the shell.
- If your shell does not start, check whether your cluster is out of resources (`kubectl describe nodes`). You can specify resource requests with `--requests`:

  ```
  --requests='': The resource requirement requests for this container.  For example, 'cpu=100m,memory=256Mi'.  Note that server side components may assign requests depending on the server configuration, such as limit ranges.
  ```

(Credit: https://gc-taylor.com/blog/2016/10/31/fire-up-an-interactive-bash-pod-within-a-kubernetes-cluster)

Comment: kubectl run test-pod --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=busybox --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent --restart=Never --rm --attach -- ping -c 5 google.com

Comment: @Dmitry where can I find this information: `$pod-container` ?

Comment: @FelipePereira you can do something like `kubectl describe po $pod` which will list all the containers running in pod, where $pod is the name of the the pod that was created by the deployment.

Comment: If you have windows nodes that are not tainted you may want to try `kubectl run tmp-shell --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"nodeSelector": { "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux" }}}' -- /bin/bash`

Comment: how do we provide security context as part of the command? I am gettting the error "Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root" when i run the command `kubectl run pod1 --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image test1 --requests='cpu=1000m,memory=1000Mi' -n testnamespace -- /bin/bash`

Comment: how do you do this in a yml file?

Comment: From kubernetes version 1.18 `kubectl run` does not create deployment anymore because all the generators were deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

In order to have a `Pod` created instead of a `Deployment` and to have it removed by itself when you exit it, try this:

```
kubectl run curl-debug --rm -i --tty --restart=Never --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -- /bin/sh
```

The `--restart=Never` flag is what it says to create a `Pod` instead of a `Deployment` object

Also - This image is lightweight, downloads fast and is good for network debugging.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Urosh! I updated my answer to include `--restart=Never`.

Comment: From kubernetes version 1.18 `kubectl run` does not create deployment anymore because all the generators were deprecated.