# kubernetes-cli command to get dns of a kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dns

I have gone through the doc mentioned here [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/blob/master/docs/specification.md) as well as [doclink](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

But my job would be a whole lot easier if I could get the dns of a resource type by using any kubernetes command.
Also tried this [commands-link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run)

For example, i would like to get the dns name of a service `db-service` running in `dev` namespace inside `svc.cluster.local`

```sh
db-service.dev.svc.cluster.local
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Except in a couple of specific cases (like pods attached to stateful sets), things that aren't services don't have DNS names, and the service name is very easy to mechanically construct.  Do you have a use case for something that's not a service that still needs this lookup?

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot @DavidMaze, I was just trying to learn more about this. I was hoping to basically get as much info from commands as possible so that I do not have to construct things mechanically :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to, you can query that in a pod:

[How do I run a container from the command line in Kubernetes (like docker run)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712874/how-do-i-run-a-container-from-the-command-line-in-kubernetes-like-docker-run)

[Retrieve the full name of a service in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559438/retrieve-the-full-name-of-a-service-in-kubernetes)

using a pod which has some DNS utils

```
kubectl run tmp-shell --rm -i --tty --image tutum/dnsutils -- /bin/bash
```

you can then run

```
root@tmp-shell:/# nslookup db-service
Server:     10.2.32.10
Address:    10.2.32.10#53

Name:   db-service.dev.svc.cluster.local
```

for a one-liner, see: https://serverfault.com/questions/929211/kubernetes-pod-dns-resolution

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
kubectl get svc
```

First column is internal DNS name.
If the type is LoadBalancer then EXTERNAL-IP column will display the external DNS name.